# Re-initialize UIView view and subview after rotation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, rotation

I have a little problem with size reset of my views after rotation and i can't fix it.

I put an "swipe" action on my view "bottomContainerView" and the size is different depending  the orientation!

here is my new code:

```
-(void)swipeToggle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    if (sender.direction ==  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){

         NSLog(@"if gesture up - LS");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -160.0, 480.0, 244.0);
                             bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 300.0);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                           NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height);                                   
                         }];

    } else if (sender.direction ==  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {

        NSLog(@"else if gesture down - LS");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -160.0, 480.0, 244.0);
                             bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 84.0, 480.0, 216.0);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height); 
                         }];
    }
}
else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    if (sender.direction ==  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {

        NSLog(@"if gesture down - PT");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 244.0);
                         bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 640.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height);
                     }];
     }
    else if (sender.direction ==  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {

        NSLog(@"else if gesture up - PT");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 244.0);
                             bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 244.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 216.0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height); 
                         }];

    }
}
```

}

POST UPDATED  - Here is my new code correct with what you taught me and kindly explain ;-)

Comment: Your animation code is a mess.  Why are you using commitAnimations /beginAnimations alongside block based animations?

Comment: Just simply because i'm newbies ! But perhaps you can explain to me why I did wrong and how to do better instead of criticizing?

Comment: especially since you seem to be a good and great ios dev!

Answer (score 0):

My eyes take damage when looking at this code.

Here you are trying to combine 2 ways of declaring animation.
If you are using `beginAnimations:` you don't have to use `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` method, but have to finish your animation code with `[UIView commitAnimations];`

The clearest way is to use `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` and put animation code inside `animations:^{}` block.

P.S: I strongly recommend not to use magic numbers in your code  and use constants instead.  SwitchToFullNormalScreen and SwitchToNormalScreen animations are just copypasted. I mean come on, that's not good.

Comment: After reading your comment I realized my mistake, so I look on the Apple doc to learn more! so I try and now I understand better!!

A big thank you to you, I learned something and I'm sure it will serve me for the future!

The only thing I do not understand is what is the "BOOL finished" at the end, I feel that it is here that should put the code to reset my views to the right size, right?

Comment: You should learn how to use Xcode inline documentation. Quote: "A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends. This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean argument that indicates whether or not the animations actually finished before the completion handler was called"

Comment: I will wish this post marked as resolved but sorry, it is not case!

Even if you have to help me understand how an animation work, the problem remains the same.

When i run the animation in LS mode and i return to portrait mode, my views do not re-initialized, and do not return to their proper sizes.

Thank you for your support but the matter will be closed, when it is really!

I work hard all the day to fix this problem and I do not succeed!