# Toggle Fullscreen action with Double Tap

Tags: ios, uiview, toggle, fullscreen

Looking for a way to implement a "full-screen" action reversible with double tap but I did not succeed!

More in detail, there are 2 UIView :
- topViewContainer
- bottomViewContainer

When I double-tap on the superview, the view "bottomViewContainer" extends to full-screen, and I re-double tap, the view returns to its original size.

It should work in portrait mode and Landscape Mode!

This is what I've done until now:

```
-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    if (sender.numberOfTapsRequired == 2){

         NSLog(@"if gesture up - LS");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -160.0, 480.0, 244.0);
                             bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 300.0);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                           NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height);                                   
                         }];

    } else if (sender.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) {

        NSLog(@"else if gesture down - LS");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -160.0, 480.0, 244.0);
                             bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 84.0, 480.0, 216.0);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height); 
                         }];
    }
}
else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    if (sender.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) {

        NSLog(@"if gesture down - PT");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 244.0);
                         bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 640.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height);
                     }];
     }
    else if (sender.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) {

        NSLog(@"else if gesture up - PT");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 244.0);
                             bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 244.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 216.0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            NSLog(@"%f,%f",bottomContainerView.frame.size.width,bottomContainerView.frame.size.height); 
                         }];

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean. What I understand is that you want to be able to double tap and have the full screen image "go back" to its original location. Some other details to include is whether or not this view that pops up, what it is displaying, if it is dynamic, etc..

Comment: One more note is that your first `elseif statement` has `condition || NO`, so that will never get called especially since your if condition matches the elseif condition

Comment: Do you want the same effect for the topContainerView or only bottomContainerView ?

Comment: Exact, yes it was a little error in my code (NO). It is the same principle here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506027/re-initialize-uiview-view-and-subview-after-rotation except that this is not a "swipe gesture" but a double tap !!!

Comment: Yes, sure, same effect !

Comment: So, simple reversed effect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    UIView *topContainerView;
    UIView *bottomContainerView;

    CGRect initialTopContainerView;
    CGRect initialBottomContainerView;

    BOOL isFullScreen;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        topContainerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, result.width, result.height/2)];
        topContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        topContainerView.tag = 1;
        [self.view addSubview:topContainerView];

        bottomContainerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, result.height/2, result.width, result.height/2)];
        bottomContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        bottomContainerView.tag = 2;
        [self.view addSubview:bottomContainerView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [bottomContainerView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
        tap2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [topContainerView addGestureRecognizer:tap2];

        initialTopContainerView = bottomContainerView.frame;
        initialBottomContainerView = topContainerView.frame;

        isFullScreen = false;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    int heightSreen = result.height;
    int widthSreen = result.width;

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        heightSreen = result.width;
        widthSreen = result.height;
    }

    if (sender.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) {

        CGRect newFrameTop;
        CGRect newFrameBottom;

        isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;

        if (isFullScreen) {

            if (sender.view.tag == 1) {
                newFrameTop = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthSreen, heightSreen);
                newFrameBottom = CGRectMake(0, heightSreen, widthSreen, 0);
            }else{
                newFrameTop = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthSreen, 0);
                newFrameBottom = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthSreen, heightSreen);
            }

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                  delay:0.1
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                             animations:^{
                                 topContainerView.frame = newFrameTop;
                                 bottomContainerView.frame = newFrameBottom;
                             }completion:nil];

        }else{

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                  delay:0.1
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                             animations:^{
                                 topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthSreen, heightSreen/2);
                                 bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, heightSreen/2, widthSreen, heightSreen/2);
                             }completion:nil];

        }

    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Amazing !!! congratulations , it work perfectly ! Just an bug fix with the landscape mode (it need reset size of views), but i think i can do this ! THANKS