# Use MPMoviePlayerController as container for UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, mpmovieplayercontroller

Working on an iOS6 app that receives an RTSP stream via FFMPEG.

Currently I am getting the stream frames in a `UIImage` and passing the `UIImage` to a `UIView` to be displayed to the user. This is working great so far, but I would like to toggle full screen while viewing the stream.

I was wondering if it is possible to use `MPMoviePlayerController` for this purpose? Since I am receiving the frames in a `UIImage` object I don't have a URL to pass to the `MPMoviePlayerController` and hence I have not been able to get this concept to work.

I would like to use the `MPMoviePlayerController` simply as a container for the `UIView` that is handling the frames currently. Does this seem like a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to get this to work, so it may not be possible. I ended up using the following answer to toggle the `UIView` in and out of full screen. Works great!

[Toggle Fullscreen action with Double Tap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553116/2525561)